# Flash Builder 4.6 Design Mode Not Working?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, designmode

I am working in Flash Builder 4.6 and I cannot get Flash Builder to display my application in design mode. I have not modified any Flash Builder configuration options, it just seems to have started on its own. Closing and opening the project, or even Flash Builder itself does not resolve the issue.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Notice how I am in design mode, but I cannot hit the "refresh design mode" arrow, and my properties panel notes that I cannot use its features unless I am in design mode, obviously not recognizing that I am in design mode.

Note the "Design Mode Problems" panel near the bottom of the screen, noting that I have a syntax error on line 33 of `Theme.mxml`, causing display issues. Here is line 33 of that file:

[image]

Notice how there isn't any error, as my application complies and runs just fine.

Any ideas as to how I can solve the display mode issues?

Thank you four your time.

Comment: How about warnings: do you have any of them in your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times when I get an error like that, I have some incorrect syntax (generally a missing parenthesis) on a line higher up. Does your code compile correctly when not in design mode? If not, check all your syntax, not just on line 33. Then try again. If that does not work, try removing chunks of code from your source and narrow down the part that is causing the problem.